# Parcelize value (inline) class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-inline-class

At first glance it seems to be okay to decorate a kotlin value (inline) class like that:

```
@JvmInline
@Parcelize
value class TestClass(val value: Long) : Parcelable
```

But the build fails reporting:

```
error: unexpected type
        public static final android.os.Parcelable.Creator<long> CREATOR = null;
                                                          ^
  required: reference
  found:    long
```

Is there a generic way to accomplish parcellation anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Uff, finally fixed in Kotlin 1.8.20-RC2.

Answer (score 2):

This was reported as an issue for inline classes on
[youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44763) and then moved to [issuertracker on google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179593149)

That said, I just tried and am not getting any build errors, with compileSDK 31 and kotlin 1.5.3